# NSE challenge: break out of deparse(substitute(...))

Tags: r, nse, non-standard-evaluation

Let's define:

```
f <- function(x) deparse(substitute(x))
```

The challenge: find `<something>` so that `f(<something>)` returns `"abc"`. Excluding, of course, `f(abc)`.

With "tidy NSE", i.e. quasiquoting, this is very easy. However, according to the NSE references ([1](http://developer.r-project.org/nonstandard-eval.pdf), [2](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html), [3](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)), it is impossible since `substitute` is a pure quoting (as opposed to quasiquoting) function.

I wonder if there is anything obscure or undocumented (not that uncommon!) that allows to unquote in `substitute`, hence the challenge.

Comment: No, there isn't. `x` is never evaluated. Thus, `f(abc)` is the only possible way to get this output.

Comment: What's the use case? What are you trying to do? Or is this just some obscure trivia challenge?

Comment: @MrFlick Obscure trivia challenge - I am not trying to hide it in the post! It was prompted by a recent question on SO about the programmatic use of a package that relies on deparse/substitute internally. Of course that was a bad choice from the package developer but I was wondering if there's really no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

@Roland is correct. Because `x` is not evaluated, there is no expression you can provide to `f` that won't be converted to a string verbatim. Quasiquotation in base R is handled by `bquote()`, which has a `.()` mechanism that works similarly to rlang's `!!`:

```
# Quasiquotation with base R
f1 <- function(x) bquote( .(substitute(x)) + 5 )


# Quasiquotation with rlang
f2 <- function(x) rlang::expr( !!rlang::enexpr(x) + 5 )

e1 <- f1(y)               # y + 5
e2 <- f2(y)               # y + 5
identical(e1, e2)         # TRUE
eval(e1, list(y=10))      # 15
```